# python - filter function for nested loop and if condition

Tags: python

I have two inputs

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

dict1={'a':[1,11],'b':[2,234],'c':[34,6]}
```

I need the results to be displayed as

```
list1 = [3,4,5]
```

Algorithm : Display the values of list1 which is not in dict1 values

Well I know this can be achieved by the below code,

```
tmp=0
for x in list1:
    for k,v in dict1.items():
        if x in v:
            tmp=1 
            break;
    if tmp:
        list1.remove(x)
        tmp=''

print list1
```

Is there anyway I can try this using filter function or any single line function?

Comment: Could you explain in text what algorithm you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure the code works?

Comment: @Manishearth: remove any entries in `list1` that are also in the list values of `dict1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, wow, I should have thought of that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dict1 = {'a':[1,11],'b':[2,234],'c':[34,6]}
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(t for _, v in dict1.items() for t in v)
print list(set1 - set2)
```

**Output**

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

**Edit:** As per bruno's suggestion

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dict1 = {'a':[1,11],'b':[2,234],'c':[34,6]}
from itertools import chain
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(v for v in chain.from_iterable(dict1.values()))
print list(set1 - set2)
```

Comment: why using `dict.items()` just to ignore the key ? What's wrong with `dict.values` ?

Answer (score 1):

Collect all list values in the dictionary into a set:

```
all_values = {v for lst in dict1.itervalues() for v in lst}
```

then filter your list on that:

```
list1 = [v for v in list1 if v not in all_values]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> dict1={'a':[1,11],'b':[2,234],'c':[34,6]}
>>> all_values = {v for lst in dict1.itervalues() for v in lst}
>>> [v for v in list1 if v not in all_values]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Hands down. Couldnt think of anything better than this :'(

Answer (score 0):

Your solution wouldn't work, you're iterating through `dict1.values()`, when what I think you intend is `dict1.items()`. That line should actually be:

```
    for v in dict1.values():
```

or

```
    for k, v in dict1.items():
```

Though you don't really need `k`, so I'd go with the first option.

What I would do would probably be more like:

```
    removeMe = []
    for v in dict1.values():
        removeMe.extend(v)
    return [i for i in list1 if i not in removeMe]
```

Comment: Actually, @Martijn Peters'  answer is better than mine. A set is faster.